# What does it mean "Found groupable relationship "OneToOne" in the VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jhipster

I'm opening my  .jdl file and  get wierd warning messages like: "Found groupable relationship "OneToOne". 
What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

It's a warning meaning that you could group several OneToOne declarations into a single one (see [JDL syntax](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#-relationship-declaration))

```
relationship OneToOne {
  JobHistory{department} to Department
}

relationship OneToOne {
  JobHistory{job} to Job
}
```

could be rewritten as:

```
relationship OneToOne {
  JobHistory{department} to Department
  JobHistory{job} to Job
}
```

If you think that this message could be improved or that this warning is not useful, you should report it on https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-ide